# Rails Best API design to get all of a record associated with a certain user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api-design, ruby-on-rails-6

This is mostly an api design question.  I have a Rails api which has routes for Users and routes for Schools.  I would like to make a single call from my front end application to the api with a param of UserId which returns all of the schools associated with that user.

What is the best way to do that?  Should I create a new route in UsersController called user-schools?  Or a new route in SchoolsController called schools-user?  Or create an entirely new controller called user-schools?  Thanks for any guidance!

PS: Getting the records from ActiveRecord in the controller is not the problem.  The problem is how to best design this api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RESTful way to define this would be through a [nested route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
GET /users/:user_id/schools
```

The same basic design principles apply here for API and "classic" applications.

You can define this by nesting the calls to the resources macro:

```
resources :users do
  resources :schools, only: [:index]
end
```

This will route `/users/:user_id/schools` to `SchoolsController#index`. While you can "sniff" for the `user_id` param:

```
class SchoolsController
  # GET /schools
  # GET /users/1/schools
  def index
    schools = if params[:user_id].present?
      user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      user.schools 
    else
      School.all
    end
    render json: schools
  end
end
```

A cleaner design is to use a seperate controller for the nested context:

```
resources :users do
  resources :schools, only: [:index], module: :users
end
```

```
module Users
  class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
    # GET /users/1/schools
    def index
      user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      render json: user.schools
    end
  end
end
```

This controller only does a single job. You could also name it `UserSchoolsController` but splitting your controllers into folders (and namespaces) makes it easier to organize them.

Comment: Great answer. Alternative approach that I think is worth mentioning (and has pros/cons to nesting) is to support a query parameter in the main controller that filters the results, (e.g. `schools?user=123` or `schools?user_id=123`).

Comment: @melcher from a RESTful design standpoint the query parameter doesn't actually imply that there is a relation between the two resources and I would only really consider it if you need a single endpoint that has a bunch of filtering options or if the parameter isn't really a relation like for example `/schools?name="Zoolander"`.

Comment: Totally agree w/ your points, and it depends on the use case and type of relationship. My assumption was that users were "associated" with a school (e.g. HABTM) but it was not a primary relationship, so nesting wouldn't necessarily make sense especially if you may need to filter by other relationships.